# How to mock a service with get() having a specific data format

Tags: angular, unit-testing, karma-jasmine, angular-test

[image]I am writing unit-test for my component and mocking a service who makes http requests for my component. The response is of following format:

```
{
  ContactActivityView :[
        {
           Code:"AB",
           IsActive:false,
        },
        {
           Code:"BC",
           IsActive:true,
        }
        ..
        ...
  ]
}
```

components.ts:

```
codesArray: ICodeModel[];

constructor(
private service: CodesService,
private messageService: MessageService) { }

ngOnInit() {
  this.getCodes();
}

getCodes() {
    this.service.getCodes()
      .subscribe((response: ICodeModel[] | []) => {
        this.codesArray = response['ContactActivityView'];
      },
      error => console.log(error)
    );
}
```

.html file:

```
 ..
  ...
    <div  class="message" *ngIf="codesArray.length === 0">
      No Data Found.
    </div>
    <div class="tbl-row" *ngFor="let code of codesArray">
      <div class="item">
        {{ code.Code }}
      </div>
      <div class="item">
        {{ code.IsActive }}
      </div>
  ..
  ...
```

service.ts:

```
getCodes(): Observable<ICodeModel[]> {
  return this._service.get(this.codeURL);
}
```

.spec file:

Here `MockCodeService` is the mocked service containing `getCodes()` funtion.

```
class MockCodesService {
  getCodes(): Observable<ICodeModel[]> {
    return of([]);
  }
}

describe('CodesComponent', () => {
  let component: CodesComponent;
  let fixture: ComponentFixture<CodesComponent>;

  beforeEach(async(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      declarations: [
        CodesComponent
      ],
      providers: [
        { provide: CommonCrudService, useClass: CommonCrudMockService },
        { provide: MessageService, useClass: MessageMockService },
        { provide: AppService, useClass: AppMockService },
        { provide: CodesService, useClass: MockCodesService }
      ],
      schemas: [NO_ERRORS_SCHEMA]
    })
    .compileComponents();
  }));

  beforeEach(() => {
    fixture = TestBed.createComponent(CodesComponent);
    component = fixture.componentInstance;
    fixture.detectChanges();
  });

  it('should create', () => {
    expect(component).toBeTruthy();
  });
});
```

The problem is when I run test, it gives me `TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined` error.

This is because when I subscribe the data in my component and store it in an array variable, it comes undefined.

And this is because `MockCodesService getCodes()` is returning an observable from an array but in my component `service.getCodes()` expects an observable from an object with a `ContactActivityView` property(response format).

So I tried to take a constant object and pass it in `MockCodesService getCodes()`:

```
const testObject = {
  ContactActivityTypeID: 2,
  Code: 'AB',
  ContactActivityTypeName: 'Associate Claims #35',
  IsActive: false,
  IsSystemCode: false,
  InUse: null,
  IsVisible: false
};
..
...
getItems() {
  return of(
    {
      ContactActivityView : [testObject]
    }
  );
}
```

But this doesn't work and still getting undefined error.

Kindly help.
Thanks.

Comment: shows what is in the CodesComponent component

Comment: @Chris Kindly have a look. Thanks.

Comment: if 'response' is an array, you cannot do this 'response[' ContactActivityView ']'

Comment: Okay. So how can I write it in the correct way? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

**component.ts**

```
codesArray: ICodeModel[] = [];

getCodes() {
  this.service.getCodes().subscribe(
    (response: { ContactActivityView: ICodeModel[] }) => {
      this.codesArray = response.ContactActivityView;
    },
    error => console.log(error),
  );
}
```

**component.spec.ts**

```
class MockCodesService {
  getCodes(): Observable<{ ContactActivityView: ICodeModel[] }> {
    return of({ ContactActivityView: [] });
  }
}
```

Comment: I think this is what I was looking for. But the code is still not working.:(  It still gives undefined error. And that's why I have also attached .html file. Kindly have a look. Thanks.

Comment: give me the constructor of the component

Comment: and the output from the console when giving the error, on which line of code gives the error

Comment: Kindly have a look. In image, 'Codes Master' gives data when I open browser dev. tool on my application, but comes blank when open on test.

Comment: Apologies but didn't understood the last one.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/212097/discussion-between-chris-and-mr-a).